# Type Coercion failing when calling dispatchEvent with custom event and "this"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert EmergencyItems::EmergencyEvent@c607bb1 to EmergencyItems.EmergencyItem.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at EmergencyItems::EmergencyItem/request()[\EmergencyItems\EmergencyItem.as:64]
```

EmergencyEvent.as

```
public class EmergencyEvent extends Event {

    public static const EVENT_REQUEST:String = "requestingr";


    public var item:EmergencyItem;

    public function EmergencyEvent(type:String, item:EmergencyItem, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.item = item;
    }

    override public function clone():Event {
        return new EmergencyEvent(type, item);
    }
}
```

EmergencyItem.as (line 64 is the one that begins with "dispatchEvent...")

```
public class EmergencyItem extends EventDispatcher {      

    public function request():void {
        dispatchEvent(new EmergencyEvent(EmergencyEvent.EVENT_REQUEST, this));
    }
}
```

I've looked around for quite a while and I can't find the problem (or a solution). I thought that maybe it could be that the "this" somehow refereed to the EmergencyEvent instead of the EmergencyItem, so I modified EmergencyItem.as

```
public function request():void {
        var self:EmergencyItem = this;
        var eEvent:EmergencyEvent = new EmergencyEvent(EmergencyEvent.EVENT_REQUEST, self);
        dispatchEvent(eEvent);
    }
```

and I still got the same error.

**Solved, I was using the wrong function when I added the event listener, copy paste error.**

Comment: What is the line that is throwing the error?  What is line 64 of the EmergencyItem class?

Comment: The line starting with dispatchEvent

Comment: @JackFlapper what is the code of the listener for this event? did you make sure that the parameter is one EmerygencyEvent?

Comment: @fmodos 
That was the problem, thank you

Comment: @JackFlapper i will post an answer about it then, so it will be helpfull for others who face the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on your listener function. The parameter type need to be of `EmergencyEvent` and not `EmergencyItem`.